# minimum number of coins to make change

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to print the minimum number of coins to make the change, if not possible print -1

In this code variable int[] c (coins array) has denominations I can use to come up with Total sum.

int total has total sum I need to come up with using coins (Unlimited supply)

```
    public static int mincoinDP(int[] c, int total) {
        int[][] a = new int[c.length + 1][total + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= c.length; i++) {
            a[i][0] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= total; j++) {
            a[0][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE - total;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= c.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= total; j++) {
                if (c[i - 1] > j) {
                    a[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE - total;
                } else {
                    a[i][j] = Math.min(a[i - 1][j], 1 + a[i][j - c[i - 1]]);
                }
            }
        }

        return a[c.length][total];
    }
```

For Sum : 4759 and Array: {31 90 8 36} Correct output is: 59
My output is: 60

What is wrong in code ?

Below is my recursive solution, trying to apply same logic in DP solution. Something seems to be wrong in logic here as well. For same input it prints -2147483595

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[] {31, 90, 8, 36};
        System.out.println(mincoin(array, 4759, 0));
    }

    public static int mincoin(int[] c, int total, int i) {

        if (total == 0) return 0;
        if (i >= c.length) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;


        int x = Integer.MAX_VALUE, y = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        if (total - c[i] >= 0) {
            x = 1 + mincoin(c, total - c[i], i);
        }
        y = mincoin(c, total, i + 1);

        return Math.min(x, y);
    }
```

Edit: Problems in code were:

1. DP version:  if (c[i -1] > j) , It is case when solution is not
   possible choosing this coin: Here we should accept solution without
   this coin which is a[i-1][j]
2. Recursive version: if(i >= c.length),
       it is terminating condition when we dont any coin at this position,
       here we should return infinity (Integer.MAX_VALUE) and
       to avoid integer overflow return Integer.MAX_VALUE - total.

Though I dont like this version of infinity, but dont see any nice way other than this here.

Comment: Could you please explain what your intention was with this could, what should happen in the loops in your Opinion. Please, also explain your variables, or at least make them more meaningful.

Comment: Instead of printing just the total number of coins, print the counts for each individual coin to find the problem.

Comment: Also, does your recursive code work, or does it show the same problem?

Comment: Added more details in question as requested in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using dynamic programming, with `a[i][j]` intended to represent the minimum number of coins (using the first i denominations) that sum to `j`. But I think your recurrence relations are off. They should be:

```
a[0][j] = 0 if j==0, otherwise infinity

a[i][j] = a[i-1][j] if c[i-1] > j
a[i][j] = min(a[i-1][j], 1 + a[i][j-c[i-1]]) if c[i-1] <= j
```

The main mistake is the `if c[i-1] > j` case in your code. You set the value to infinity (or your variant of infinity), but you should just copy the minimum number of coins from the previous row since you may be able to construct the total using the smaller number of coins.

By the way, there is a neater way to write this code. In pseudocode:

```
a = new int[total+1]
for int j = 1 to total+1 {
    a[j] = infinity
}
for int coin in coins {
    for j = coin to total+1 {
        a[j] = min(a[j], a[j-coin]+1)
    }
}
```

It's essentially the same algorithm, but it uses a smaller one-dimensional array which it modifies in-place.

Comment: What you said main mistake was exactly answer I was looking for, Additional comment are helpful as well.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you could have done some more debugging yourself by testing small cases. For example, coins [1, 2] total 1 will fail. Once you have a tiny reproduction case it's much easier to debug since you can run the code by hand to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately small test cases I tried were all successful, after looking at problem it comes in mind it will fail on [1, 2] and total.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone looking for solution

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    int dp[][] = new int[coins.length+1][amount+1];
    Arrays.sort(coins);
    
    // First column of every row
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; ++i) {
        dp[i][0] = 0;
    }

    /*
       Setting this so that this is default max value. We always
       want our dp[i][j] better than this
    */
    for (int j = 0; j <= amount; ++j) {
        dp[0][j] = amount+1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= coins.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= amount; ++j) {
            if (coins[i-1] > j) {
               dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];   // Take the already best value in above row
            } else {
               dp[i][j] = Math.min(dp[i-1][j], 1 + dp[i][j-coins[i-1]]); // Take the best of above row and using current coin
            }
        }
    }
    if (dp[coins.length][amount] > amount) { // it means we cannot find any coin
        return -1;
    } else {
        return dp[coins.length][amount];
    }
}
```